# How can I disable the "Include surrounding text" setting, once enabled?

Tags: chrome-for-android

Chrome has for the last year and a half had a bug where the "Mark text to search" feature breaks if you enable "Include surrounding text". You can [read more about the bug here](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/257310329/enabling-include-surrounding-text-breaks-android-s-search-by-touch-feature-how-to-disable?hl=en&sjid=6269031410214336237-EU), but the thing I would like to know is how to work around it by simple disabling the "Include surrounding text" option/flag. I have not been able to find it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the Chrome app, from the overflow (3 vertical dots) menu, select **Settings**.
2. Select **Google services**.
3. Tap **Touch to Search**.
4. Tap **Include surrounding text in Google searches**.

Comment: THANK YOU. That was well hidden. For some reason, the search company Google has chosen not to make these settings searchable :)